# Is there a way to copy values from one key:value map to another?

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to copy the values of one map to another one, some of the values are stored as strings, and some of them as arrays or lists.
For example:

```
map 1: {
    "name"        : "target_name",
    "description" : "item_desc",
    "status"      : "status",
    "budget: [ { "timeframe": "", "type": "", "amount":""  } ]
    }"
```

I wrote a function that receives a map (like the one above) and a JSON raw result, and scans the JSON response for the matching key and value pair.
 For example,`"name":  "target_name"`
 "name" is the key at the map
`"target_name"` is the key from the JSON.

once I encounter a nested value like:

```
"budget: [ { "timeframe": "", "type": "", "amount":""  } ]"
```

I get stuck, i dont know how to reach the keys from the JSON response.
attached here is the code ive written:

```
     function oneOffrAppendToData(map,jsonResultRaw) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(getTemplate())
        for(var mapkey in map ){
            for(var key in jsonResultRaw){
                if(map[mapkey]==key){
                    for(var jsonKey in jsonData){
                        if(jsonKey==mapkey){
                            jsonData[jsonKey]=jsonResultRaw[key]
                        }
                    }
                    //jsonData.mapkey =jsonResultRaw[key]

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, in particular the part in capitals.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary in Javascript

Comment: @Dexygen ...this is both pedantic and false. Objects act like a kind of dictionary, and ES6 added the Map object.

Comment: Can you clearly specify what are the two objects you have before the operation and the result you expect?

Comment: @Domino First of all thanks for the comments. I have an api GET request which gives me a json file, i would like to take the data from the JSON file, and to write some kind of a converter that will change this JSON from one format to another. The map object consists of 1.value: the parameter name from the JSON . 2.key: The new parameter name i would like for the data. Scanning the map for the values and appending them to the new map/array works for me well until i encounter a nested value at the JSON like this one :"budget: [ { "timeframe": "", "type": "", "amount":""  } ].

Comment: Your input is `{ budget: [ { timeframe: "", type: "", amount: ""} ]`. What do you want the output to be? If budget is always a 1-element array and you're just trying to copy the properties from that element, you can just access it with `budget[0].timeframe`, `buget[0].type`, `budget[0].amount` and not bother with loops. You're not giving us enough information about your goal for us to help.

Comment: The output should be the same value which is stored under { budget: [ { timeframe: "", type: "", amount: ""} ] but under a different name, lets say {payout: [ {amount:"", typeof:"", from:""} ] }

Comment: @Domino It is neither pedantic nor false.  In Javascript they are objects, in C# and Python they are dictionaries.  Using the dictionary tag in Javascript is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you don't do this by scanning JSON or anything like that. Use objects and recursion.

From what I gather of your post, you want to scan a map (oldmap) with properties that may have values as arrays. When you find one of these properties, as long as its value isn't an array, you want to write the key/val to another object (newmap). If it is an array, you want to continue scanning it (the recursion).

One problem, is that if you find the same property name twice and write it to your new object, it'll overwrite the old one. That's a solvable problem but I'll let that for now to focus on your specific example.

This code scans "oldmap" for a list of properties, and if it finds it, writes that key/val to a "newmap".

First, it checks to see if you've fed it an array. If so, it pulls the first object and checks again. This recurses until it finds something that isn't an array (we'll assume here that it'll either find an array, or a map, nothing else).

When it finds an object, it goes through it's keys and does the newmap write if an indicated property is found. If it finds an array as one of the values of that object, it recurses again. This recursion eventually gets to the end of the nesting and unwinds back to the top, resulting in your map.

I wrote this kind of off the cuff, I could probably avoid having  two blocks that check the arrays, but I think for now this is a straightforwardly easy to follow example of what I'm tryin to get at.

Also, I could extend this by feeding in a list of values, such that if key N is found, I could write it to the new object with val N. That's not part of your request though at this point.

```
const oldmap = {
"name":  "target_name",
"description": "item_desc",
"status":"status",
"budget": [
    {
        "timeframe": "",
        "type": "",
        "amount":"" 
    }
  ]
};

const newMap = {};
function createNewMap ( map, keys ) {
    if ( Array.isArray ( map ) && map.length ) {
      createNewMap ( map [ 0 ], keys );
    }
    Object.keys ( map ).forEach ( x => {
      if ( keys.indexOf ( x ) >= 0 ) {
        newMap [ x ] = map [ x ];
      }
      if ( Array.isArray ( map [ x ] ) && map [ x ].length >= 0  ) {
        createNewMap ( map [ x ], keys );
      } 
    });
}

createNewMap ( oldmap, [ 'name', 'type', 'amount' ] );
console.log ( newMap );
// Output: {name: "target_name", type: "", amount: ""}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed explanation. I have an api GET request which gives me a json file, i would like to take the data from the JSON file, and to write some kind of a converter that will change this JSON from one format to another. The map object consists of 1.value: the parameter name from the JSON . 2.key: The new parameter name i would like for the data. Scanning the map for the values and appending them to the new map/array works for me well until i encounter a nested value at the JSON like this one :"budget: [ { "timeframe": "", "type": "", "amount":""  } ].

Comment: Hmm, my assumption was you understood how to work with JSON, look up "JSON.stringify" which coverts an object to JSON, and "JSON.parse" which converts JSON strings to objects, if the string is valid JSON. My example also shows how to deal with nested lists. The end result is a new map based on the old one, which based on my example above and whatever tweaks you need to the format of the new map, you can build any way you like. As far as I can tell, this shows how to accomplish what you're asking.